# Deleted GRUB root directory. How do I reinstall grub?

Tags: grub

I have the following partition structure

```
/dev/loop0 squashfs
/dev/sda1  system reserved ( ntfs )
/dev/sda2  ntfs ( windows partition )
/dev/sda3  ntfs 
/dev/sda5  ntfs
/dev/sda6  ext4
```

I have Ubuntu installed inside windows. I formatted /dev/sda6 from inside Ubuntu ( using Gparted ). What I totally forgot was /dev/sda6 had Fedora which was the root directory of GRUB. Now how do I recover grub. I have tried chrooting to the ubuntu partition and installing grub. But the boot fails with, " No such device... ". And I cannot install elementaryOS on /dev/sda6 since the installer doesn't go beyond a couple of windows.

Comment: Which version? There are several versions of GRUB, which are incompatible with each other.

Comment: Does the Ubuntu installer you used have a rescue mode that just does a grub reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenSuse, this problem could be solved by doing a recovery installation. This reinstalls all programs which are delivered with the installer, including Grub.
As all Ubuntu installers I have ever used had Grub included, I guess this will also works for you, but as I am not eager to duplicate your problem, it isn't guaranteed that Grub will succesfull be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use SuperGrub from http://www.supergrubdisk.org/
Download the iso burn to pen drive or cd and boot into live mode.
Follow the onscreen GUI instructions to reinstall and fix the grub.